# Simple definition of karma according to Hinduism

Tags: karma, terminology

I wanted to ask about the simple definition of karma according to Hinduism. In most websites or sources I've come across Karma means Action/Deed, but on one website it says "Karma means only good deeds. Bad deeds can never be considered as karma".

So my question is, according to Hinduism, does Karma mean Action/Deed, or does it mean Good Action/ Good Deed?

Kindly note that the intent of my question is to simply gain clarification on this translation/definition rather than go into a deep elaboration on the law of karma/ Karma in general.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In general terms , it means that nothing happens by chance,unbound by law of causation (cause effect chain - It is impossible to reap whatever is not sown). Karma derives its meaning from कृ which means to act/do.(mental,vocal, physical). , disregarding good /bad/mixed...
Sometimes karma may connote a ritualistic activity which is applicable only in certain context.

Answer (score 0):

Karma means deeds only. Whether deeds are good or bad will be decided by following kartha who elongates the karma to generations.
Accordingly human Janma varies. Karma depending upon time, place, materials and followers can take three paths:

KOOTASTHA: One who conquers all hearts
MITHYACHARA: A hypocrite who manipulates truth & lies often for fame and survival.
SHARANYA: One who sees all peaceful as God

The first 2 have bondage and are not liberated.